# Cron job executes in browser but not in terminal

Tags: php, curl, cron, command

Hello i'm having problems running this cron script in the terminal,

`http://subdomain.website.com/database.php?password=mypassword`

When I paste this cron script in the browser it works and downloads the file to my local server but in the terminal it fails to execute, I've read numerous articles on the internet and they say that you cannot use special arguments in your cron like "?password=mypassword"

I've tried to reinvent this command many ways to no avail, curl, get, wget and wget -q do not work either.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To execute PHP from the command line with arguments, you call it like so:

```
$ php /path/to/php/file arg1 arg2 arg3
```

Then, within your PHP script you access the argument list using

```
$argv[0] // would return /path/to/php/file/
$argv[1] // returns arg1
$argv[2] // returns arg2
```

If you want to make your script so that it can be accessed both via the terminal and browser, you could do something like this:

```
$password = isset($argv[1]) ? $argv[1] : $_GET['password'];
```

Though if you're using this for a CRON and you need arguments, then your program architecture is bad. You should hard code these arguments within your script, such as a variable/property/etc.

Comment: You're right the program architecture is pretty bad, thanks for the help, i should throw the program away if it's giving me this much trouble.